# I have a URL problem in Google arabic site

Tags: url, search-engine-indexing, google-search-console

I made an Arabic site using Google new sites. The page titles have to be in Arabic. When I write the page title in Arabic, the URL looks funny.

Google indexing did not happen in 3 months while requesting indexing in Google search console everyday.

Comment: I'm not sure why Google is not indexing it (I don't really know how that works), but the Arabic in the URL looks perfectly fine to me. If you're worried that the Arabic might be causing difficulties, you can either transliterate or translate the page URLs so they're all ASCII. A lot of Arabic websites do that.

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply. I am an arabic speaker so the arabic is correct. But i do not understand what is ASCII and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Google is not indexing it (I don't really know how that works), but the Arabic in the URL looks perfectly fine to me. If you're worried that the Arabic might be causing difficulties, you can either transliterate or translate the page URLs so they're all ASCII (ASCII is the most basic set of English characters.)

One way to do this would be to convert your URLs into a "slug", which is a url-safe string. There's a good package `slugify` that does this:

```python
import slugify

>>> slugify.slugify("هذا النص بالعربية")
'hdh-lns-bl-rby'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When I try

`site:https://sites.google.com/view/skindiseaseinfo` in **google.com**, it shows three pages have been indexed.

**So, your site is getting indexed.**  The question then is why aren't your other pages getting indexed.  Google decides what pages to index based on its own rules.  You can improve the chances by following the guidelines

> - Remove crawl blocks in your robots.txt file
> - Remove rogue noindex tags
> - Include the page in your sitemap
> - Remove rogue canonical tags
> - Check that the page isn’t orphaned
> - Fix nofollow internal links
> - Add “powerful” internal links
> - Make sure the page is valuable and unique
> - Remove low-quality pages (to optimize “crawl budget”)
> - Build high-quality backlinks

From [ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-index/)

Finally, for a new site, it can take some time before Google trusts your site to index more pages.  There can also be "errors" that Google does not like.  It does not always spell out the reason.  I have found that **Yandex** will give you a better reason for failure.  If you follow its recommendations (and recommendations from website checking sites) then you the improve the chances of getting your pages indexed.